# How to fill the background image on the full screen. Currently it leaves the nav bar with a whitespace. and the image is cut from the top

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried wrapping the "parallax-img" class around my  main content but that removes the navigation bar once I scroll down and reach the landing page limit.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2aTv.jpg)

i will link my Github down for the code:
https://github.com/pr1thvicoder/fitnessproject.git

Comment: Include the code in the question itself

Comment: Please read: [Can I just link to my website?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428) and [why an image of your code is not acceptable](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Both links provide reasons that also apply to your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY USING Z-INDEX BY MAKING IMAGE ON TOP AND NAV-BELOW AND ADD SOME SPACING ON TOP OF IMAGE TO ALIGN IT WITH NAVBAR